# Solve equation $xy^2-(3x^2-4x+1)y+x^3-2x^2+x=0$ , in $\mathbb R$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, quadratics

Solve equation $xy^2-(3x^2-4x+1)y+x^3-2x^2+x=0$ , in $\mathbb R$

This question was asked by another user but unfortunately was deleted when I was typing the answer. I did not want my time wasted, so I asked it again with new condition.

Solution:

Let $y=tx$ we get:

$(t^2-3t+1)x^3+2(2t-1)x^2+(1-t)x=0$

$x=0$

$(t^2-3t+1)x^2+2(2t-1)x+(1-t)=0$

$\Delta'=(2t-1)^2+(t-1)(t^2-3t+1)=k^2$

$\Delta'=t^3=k^2$

If $t=a^2$ then $t^3=(a^3)^2=k^2$

For $a∈\mathbb N$ we can have infinite solutions;

$(t, k)=(1, 1), (4, 8), (9, 27), \cdot\cdot\cdot$

$(t, k)=1, 1$  ⇒$(x, y)=(0, 0),(-2, -2) $

$(t, k)=(4, 8)$ ⇒ $(x, y)=(3, 12), (-\frac 15, -\frac 45)$

$(t, k) =(9, 27)$ ⇒ $(x, y)=(\frac 45, \frac{36}5),(\frac{-2}
{11}, -\frac{18}{11})$

Any alternative solution?

Here is a plot by wolfram

[image]

Comment: just see that the expression is a quadratic in y

Comment: Are you sure there is no typo in the question?

Comment: To elaborate @TobyMak's comment i see $x^3-2x+x$ which may be $x^3-2x^2+x$??

Comment: $(x,y)=(-2,-2),(3,12)$ are not solutions even for $xy^2-(3x^2-4x+1)y+x^3-2x^2+x=0$.

Comment: @TobyMak,true , I corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you put $y=ax$, since this is clearly a quadratic equation in $y$: $$xy^2-(3x^2-4x+1)y+x^3-2x^2+x=0$$

Its discriminant is $$D=(3x-1)^2(x-1)^2-4x^2(x-1)^2=(x-1)^3(5x-1)$$

So $y$ is defined for $x\in \left(-\infty,{1\over 5}\right]\cup [1,\infty)$ and $x\ne 0$: $$y={(x-1)\Big(3x-1\pm \sqrt{(x-1)(5x-1)}\Big)\over 2x}$$

Comment: Aqua, There was a typo, I corrected it. please edit your answer and also give few numeric solutions. thanks. +1

Comment: @Albus, That is what Aqua did, but I do not think finding root will be easy. The advantage of my method is that you can find solutions easily. Lets wait to see how Aqua expands his solution and gives some numbers.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what are you expecting to do now?

Comment: @Aqua He expects you to give some numbers as solutions. (He replied to some comment from user @Albus.)

Comment: Why? @ultralegend5385

Comment: Ask him, I don't know!

Comment: @Aqua, I mean how would you solve $(x-1)(5x-1)=k^2$

Comment: What is kind of a number is $k$?

Comment: He wants some $x$ such that $(x-1)(5x-1)$ is a perfect square. ($k\in\mathbb{Z}$)

Comment: Well, I suppose $x$ is also an integer? This is completly new task and should be post as another question.

Comment: I asked the solution in $\mathbb R$, that means it can also be rational.

Comment: I realy needed  that down vote, thank you down voter.

Comment: well i'm not the one